# How do split string with number elements and white space and store it into an indexable array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures, queue

I am having some difficulty getting my input and getting it stored into an array. I am making a stock exchange type program where a user will enter if they want to buy, sell, or calculate capital gain of their shares. So basically the input would be taken in using a scanner and storing it into a variable. Then it would call a method, using the variable in the parameter and parsing it so that it can be split into 3 parts.

My input will consist of a string element followed by integer type values. So this is what my input would look like when the program starts:

B 20 300

This means that I will be buying 20 shares at $300. Is there a way for me to store all of this as first a string into an array and then converting the values at index 1 and 2 so that it will be an int? I would really appreciate some help so that I can get my input to start working. This is what I've been trying to do:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class StockTran {
static String command = "";
String[] stockParts = null;
CircleArrayQueue Q = null;

public StockTran(String inputCommand) {
    try {
        this.stockParts = this.parseInput(command);
        System.out.println(stockParts[0]);
        System.out.println(stockParts[1]);
        System.out.println(stockParts[2]);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private String[] parseInput(String inputLine) throws Exception {
    String[] temp = inputLine.split("\\s");
    return temp;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter 'B' to purchase share, 'S' to sell share, 'C' for capital gain, or 'Q' to quit: ");
    command = reader.next();

    StockTran tran = new StockTran(command);
}
```

}

Comment: You can rather do that while printing the array in your constructor..

Comment: If I try doing that, then it gives me the following error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at StockTran.<init>(StockTran.java:19)
 at StockTran.main(StockTran.java:38)

Comment: It does however print the letter B, it will just give me an error after B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read a complete line to pass to your constructor for splitting into elements:

```
command = reader.nextLine();
```

as

```
command = reader.next();
```

will only read the first token.

Comment: Oh ok, well that certainly will make things work accordingly. Thank you for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class tcs {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String customerDetails = scanner.nextLine();
    String string[]=customerDetails.split("\\s");
    for (int i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(string[i]);
    }
    //System.out.println(string[0]);
    //System.out.println(string[1]);
    //System.out.println(string[2]);
    int total=Integer.parseInt(string[1])*(Integer.parseInt(string[2]));
    System.out.println(total);
    }
}
```